# HTTP POST request in Swift

Tags: swift, http-post

How do I post the request on iOS? Actually when I logged into Facebook it fetches the user informations like username, from where there are login (latitude, longitude). Is it possible to use api 
Link: http://buddysin.aumkiiyo.com/fbc

My code is:

```
@IBAction func btnAPI(sender: UIButton)
{
    //startConnection()
    connectToWebAPI()
}
func connectToWebAPI()
{ 
    //setting up the base64-encoded credentials
    let id = "1620912344817986"
    //let password = "pass"
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", id)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

    //creating the requestz
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://buddysin.aumkiiyo.com/fbc")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            // converting the data into Dictionary
            var error: NSError?
            let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

            println(jsonResult)
        }
    })

    //fire off the request  

    task.resume()
}
```

while I run, the fatal error where displayed as

```
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
```

in the "jsonResult"

Comment: on which line you got this error?

Comment: let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

Comment: try  `if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as?NSDictionary{ println(jsonResult) }`

Comment: when i changed the code no error where displayed it shows "nil"

Comment: In my o/p it shows:    Optional({
    share =     {
        message = " API AUTH FaileD";
        status = "-1";
    };
})

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better to use [Alomafire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). As AFNetWorking in Objective-C it is a library which simplified a lot http request.

Comment: what i should do after i download the alomafire

Comment: When you have added Alomafire in your XCode Project. You can find some example in the github. For example an example to make a http.post : [link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You should find which varible due to this error:
for example `data`,

```
if let dataTemp = data as? NSDictionary {
}
```

FYI:
  Here is a way of 'POST' method of `AFNetworking` in swift, below code should be in your `connectToWebAPI` method, wrap your url ready into NSURL.

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: yourURL))
manager.POST("path", parameters: ["key":value], success: { (opeartion:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, data:AnyObject!) -> Void in
        },failure: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    })
```

Tutorial to install `AFNetworking`.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Comment: so i should have to change the code completely write!! and where do i have to paste this code.. i have no idea about this code.

Comment: if i implement this code in my connectToWebAPI() its shows some error like /* Use of Unresolved AFHTTPRequestOperationManager */ , /* Use of declared type AFHTTPRequestOperation */ . how should i resolve the errors.

Comment: Oh, suggest to use *AFNetworking* for http/https on IOS development. Nearly no app with interact with backend/API won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

- Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988835/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-http-post-with-custom-json-body/31990454#31990454) question to check for my post-request function (if
  you don't want to use Alamofire for any reasons)
- Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706589/how-to-add-alamofire-to-xcode-project-swift)    question to check for steps you need to do if you 
  want to add    Alamofire to your XCode-project
- If you need to get json-data from    your server, use
  [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It's as simple as dragging    SwiftyJSON.swift into 
  your project with checking "Copy items if    needed" and using like

> let jsonData = JSON(data: yourDataFromServer)

- Also you can view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988835/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-http-post-with-custom-json-body/31990454#31990454) question to check out for steps to encode
  json-post data to send it to server.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: where i should create the PHP file, if i'm not using alamofire @SwiftStudier

Comment: You don't have to. It was just example

Comment: I answered on your question. Your service auth problems does not conform this topic, it's your own

Comment: okay how should i display the logged user details please tell .. actually in that example they predefined set the values but i want to get and display the details while run time from the server is it possible??

Comment: your question is about HTTP POST request in swift, isn't it?

Comment: so user details displaying is another. feel it

Comment: actually i'm in learning stage of swift, okay thanks for ur guidance

Comment: you should accept right answer on this topic question and ask another if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

```
  func postSomething(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler){
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", id)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "base64LoginString",
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "parameter": value,
        "parameter2": value2
    ]

    Alamofire.request("http://buddysin.aumkiiyo.com/fbc", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: SFAppServicesManager.sharedInstance.genericHeader()).responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            let userDictionary = JSON as! NSDictionary
            completionHandler(true)
        } else {
            completionHandler(false)
        }
    }
}
```